# If this isn't irony, what is it?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I was reading a piece by a blogger who was reviewing some material from a particular industry. The author at a few points in the article made the point that the professionals in the topic industry "weren't trying" and were "making a poor effort" in their chosen field. Unfortunately, the author for the piece littered the article with grammatical mistakes (I stopped counting at 30 in a single post).

Seeing as how these types of mistakes could show that the author was "making a poor effort" I was thinking this could be described as an example of irony but [the definitions I found](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony) from MW would seem to preclude that.

I felt it was important to get the right description since I am making a commentary about the author's lack of attention to basic English grammar. ;)

Comment: An example of [Muphry's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry%27s_law)

Comment: Voting to close because OP's example **is** ironic. Making it "general reference".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Definition 3a1 on [the page you link to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irony), "incongruity between the actual result of a sequence of events and the normal or expected result", seems to fit: the expected output of someone who complains about poor effort shows signs of good effort.

Comment: you mean "shows signs of poor effort"?

Comment: @kdmurray, no, I meant what I wrote, I think. The *expected* output of someone who complains of poor effort shows signs of *good* effort; that expectation was not fulfilled.

Comment: right. I really shouldn't do this at 23:30. :P That's probably why the definition didn't seem to fit when I read it on the website.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite definition of *irony*: poetic injustice.